# segmentation fault in vector of vector swap,allocate memory to pointer to vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector

struct Pos contains start and end
substringPos vector contains one Pos
array vector of vector of Pos contains substringPos
size of array is incremented by permutation numbers by reserve call
the 1st element substringPos of array is duplicated to other elements of array by swap call

```
 struct Pos
    {
    int start;
    int end;
    };

    typedef vector<Pos*> PosVector;
    vector<struct Pos*>substringPos;
    struct Pos*temp=new Pos;
    temp->start=3;
    temp->end=10;
    substringPos.push_back(temp);



    vector<PosVector*> array;
    array.push_back(&substringPos);
    array.reserve(permutations);    
    for(int v=1;v<permutations-1;v++)
    {
        array[v]->push_back(temp);//gives segmentation fault
        array[v]->swap(*array[0]);//gives segmentation fault

    }
```

Comment: That can't be the real code. It uses `substringPos` before it's declared.

Comment: `array` contains exactly one element; the only valid index is `array[0]`. Since `i` and `permutations` are never shown it's difficult to be sure, but chances are `i + v` is greater than `0`, and your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing index out of bounds.

Comment: This is *prime* for running a debugger.

Comment: Why are you storing dynamically allocated pointers in vector? vector provides you with memory management that allows get rid of all raw new calls. If you still need pointers due to inheritance - use std::unique_ptr

Comment: I think array[v] is not allocated with memory, how to allocate?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<PosVector*> array;
array.push_back(&substringPos);
array.reserve(permutations);    
for(int v=1;v<permutations-1;v++)
{
    array[v]->push_back(temp);//gives segmentation fault
    array[v]->swap(*array[0]);//gives segmentation fault
}
```

This code exhibits an undefined behavior. Lets pretend, that `permutations` variable is initialized and greater than 1. When you call `array.reserve` you allocate memory in the `array` vector to store `permutations` count of elements. Each element is a pointer to the `PosVector`. Since you never initialize them, an attempt to resolve uninitialized pointer leads to the undefined behavior and in your case you get a segmentation fault. Perhaps it would be better to store vectors itself, instead of pointers?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to vector subscript out of range.Vector or array should start at index 0.
Please change for loop as below

```
for(int v=0;v<permutations-1;v++)
{
  // your code
}
```